# django inlineformset, how to allow only 1 boolean field to be true at a time?

Tags: python, django

I have an inline formset. 1 of the attribute of the inline model is a boolean. I wish to keep only 1 of them set to True at any point of time. How can this be achieved. I have tried:

```
class AmodelFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    model = Amodel

    def clean(self):
        for form in self.forms:
            if form.instance.current: #current is the boolean attribute
                try:
                    temp = Amodel.objects.filter(current=True)
                    if form.instance not in temp:
                        for t in temp:
                            t.current = False
                            t.save()
                except Amodel.DoesNotExist:
                    pass
```

With this I am able to get only when saved forms have the boolean values. But existing form if more than 1 values are set to 'True', both get boolean 'True' while requirement is to set only 1 of them to True. I am unable to raise Exception for this. How can I do this? Django v.1.6.5

Comment: So you are saying that if any previously filled forms are `True`, you want to raise an `Exception`?

Comment: @Scironic only 1 value in the given formset should have boolean 'True'  at any point of time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach of subclassing `BaseFormset` and adding [custom validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/formsets/#custom-formset-validation) looks good. You should check the contents of the form's `cleaned_data`, instead of fetching the value from the db.

```
class MyBaseFormSet(BaseFormSet):
    def clean(self):
        """Checks that only one instance is current"""
        if any(self.errors):
            # Don't bother validating the formset unless each form is valid on its own
            return
        count = 0
        for form in self.forms:
            if form.cleaned_data['current']:
                count += 1
                if count > 1:
                    raise forms.ValidationError("Only one item can be current")
```

Then create the model formset using `modelformset_factory`

```
from django.forms.models import modelformset_factory
MyFormSet = modelformset_factory(MyModel, formset=MyBaseFormSet)
```